# Ion Mass Spectrometry of Polymorphs

Tags: organic-chemistry

Can ion mass spectrometry differentiate between 2 distinct polymorphs? Why?

In my opinion, the spectrum would be the same as only the crystal lattice differs.

Comment: [Here’s an example](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4096336/). In short, surface analysis with SIMS seems to allow them to calculate the ratio of oxygens bound to calcium atoms from the surface which can be used to distinguish polymorphs

Comment: That articles mentions a time-of-flight secondary ion mass spectroscopy (TOF-SIMS). Would it be the same with a simple IMS?

Comment: Because I believe that IMS will provide similar Ko values as only the lattice changes in polymorphs.

Comment: simple IMS? Not really sure what your referring too could you provide a reference/example of a simple IMS